# ArgumentException - Invalid Parameter by a FolderBrowseDialog? (vb.net)

Tags: vb.net

I have a bigger project and a problem which i can' figure out in it:

```
  Do Until Directory.Exists(xmlpath)
            Dim opendir As New FolderBrowserDialog
            opendir.RootFolder = Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop
            opendir.SelectedPath = "C:\"
            If (opendir.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK) Then
                xmlpath = opendir.SelectedPath
            End If
            opendir.Dispose()
        Loop
```

So soon the programm comes to the Line "If (opendir.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK) Then" i get this error:

> System.ArgumentException wurde nicht behandelt.   HResult=-2147024809 
>   Message=Ungültiger Parameter.   Source=System.Drawing   StackTrace:
>          bei System.Drawing.Image.get_Flags()
>          bei System.Windows.Forms.ControlP aint.IsImageTransparent(Image backgroundImage)
>          bei System.Windows.Forms.Control.PaintBackground(PaintEventArgs e, Rectangle rectangle, Color backColor, Point scrollOffset)
>          bei System.Windows.Forms.Control.PaintBackground(PaintEventArgs e, Rectangle rectangle)
>          bei System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs pevent)
>          bei System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs
>   e)
>          bei System.Windows.Forms.Control.PaintWithErrorHandling(PaintEventArgs e,
>   Int16 layer)
>          bei System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmPaint(Message& m)
>          bei System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
>          bei System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
>          bei System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
>          bei System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
>          bei System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)   InnerException:

Please forgive me that a few parts are german but i really have no idea why that error even comes.

Its a given that the framework uses the Drawing Class for Controls but why should it run on an error where it was working before?

EDIT:
15.08.2015

Well, i have reason to update it - got the Dialog to show - pretty much just moved it to a different location to be called.

The Problem is, that i still get the ArgumentException, but now for a line where i change the height of a groupbox control.

It seems to be a rather random Exception?

Comment: The exception has very little to do with the code snippet.  You have set the BackgroundImage property of a control to a bitmap that is not valid anymore.  Perhaps because it was disposed.  You *might* get it to bomb with the dialog on an old Windows version.  Then closing the dialog can cause whatever is underneath the dialog to repaint.  You need to fix this by ensuring that the BackgroundImage property stays valid.

Answer (score -1):

Use `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)` instead of `Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop`

Comment: Sadly it has nothing to do with the expection. But is a useful tip.